# offcanvas jquery trigger not working in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jasny-bootstrap

I have included [jasny's bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas-examples) offcanvas menu in a react app. 
While I can trigger and hide the open menu through console in [jasny's example](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/) like so:

```
$('.navmenu').offcanvas('hide')
```

But doing the same in my react app is throwing error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offcanvas is not a function(…)

I am guessing its got something to do with javascript closure. Is there any other way to trigger this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to trigger like this on my page load:

```
      if(window.innerWidth > 1000)
          document.getElementById('navbar-toggle').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:

```
// to show it
let myOffcanvas = new window.bootstrap.Offcanvas(document.getElementById('offcanvasId'))
myOffcanvas.show();
```

and then

```
// to hide it
let myOffcanvas = window.bootstrap.Offcanvas.getInstance(document.getElementById('offcanvasId'))
myOffcanvas.hide();
```